# Why do we neglect the protons from water's autoprotolysis?

Tags: ph

Why don't we need to consider the $\ce{H+}$ ions of water when finding the $\ce{pH}$ of $0.01~\mathrm{M}$ of $\ce{HCl}$ solution?

The $\ce{pH}$ value of something is depending on the molarity of $\ce{H+}$ ions. But the teachers says the calculation is just $-\log(0.01)$, don't we need to consider the $\ce{H+}$ ions of water?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could consider them, but what would be the result?

$0.01 M$ of $\ce{HCl}$ with $1\times10^{-7} M$ of $\ce{H^+}$ from water gives you $0.0100001 M$ of $H^+$. Find the pH of this concentration of $\ce{H^+}$ and compare with the pH you would obtain if you used $0.01 M$ directly.

You shouldn't see that the resulting pH differ significantly.

Answer (score 3):

Do note, however, that the self-ionization of water technically must be taken into account. Though very often justifiable, it is an *approximation* to leave it out. Ask yourself, what is the pH of a $10^{-8}\  mol.L^{-1}$ solution of $\ce{HCl}$? It doesn't make sense to add a strong acid to pure water, however dilute, and obtain a basic pH! If you don't rely on the approximate formula, you will find that such a solution has a pH of about 6.98.

[Here](http://www2.chem.ubc.ca/courseware/pH/section16/index.html) is a good source to get you going. The more proper way of solving for $\ce{[H^+]_{eq}}$ is based on the solution of a polynomial found from the combination of the charge balance equation and chemical entity balance equations along with equilibria constant definitions, and it is detailed [here](http://www2.chem.ubc.ca/courseware/pH/section16/weak.html). Though used specifically to analyse the behaviour of a weak acid solution, the same equations can be used for the strong acid solution, with the added approximation that $\ce{[HA]_{eq}} \approx  0$ (i.e. $\ce{c_{HA}} \approx \ce{[A^{-}]}$).