# How do I find pH of a mixture of weak acids?

Tags: equilibrium, ph

Suppose that we are given two weak bases $\ce{HA_1}$ and $\ce{HA_2}$. We are also given the $K_\ce{HA_1}$ and $K_\ce{HA_2}$. How can we calculate the $\mathrm{pH}$ of the mixture?

Comment: It depends... The "full" treatment would consider both HA species and the $K_w$ of water. Depending on the values of $K_{HA_1}$ and $K_{HA_2}$ and the concentrations various approximations may be appropriate.

Comment: @Mithoron No. That question is different. In that question we are given the pH of both acids whereas in this question we are given some other information. Only the title looks quite similar.

Comment: @AdityaJain I answered your question [here](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/120139/80491).